# javascript - How do I show and hide an element using keyboard keys?

Tags: javascript

I just made a questioner application. There is a Next and Previous function and a button with javascript where I hide and show questions.

I want to create a key shortcut from Next and Previous, examples:

Left Arrow -> it will go to the previous question
Right Arrow -> it will go to the next question

The following is an excerpt from my script:

```
<form>
  <div id="question1" class="cont active"> </ div>
  <div id="question2" class="cont hide"> </ div>
  <div id="question3" class="cont hide"> </ div>
</form>
```

When I push Arrow Right, then `div#question` should hide and `div#question2` should be active, and the opposite if I push Arrow Left. I'm stuck, I've looked for references and hope someone can help.

Comment: what you have done so far? can use any javascript library? jquery?

Comment: show us some code / create jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

To capture the key presses you could try:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){

  if(e.key == "ArrowLeft" && e.target == document.body){
    //left arrow
  }
  if(e.key == "ArrowRight" && e.target == document.body){
    //right arrow
  }
}
```

To hide an element you could use, for example:

```
document.getElementById('question1').style.display = "none";
```

and to show again:

```
document.getElementById('question1').style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Please note `event.keyCode`, `event.charCode`, `event.which`, and others are deprecated, use `event.key` instead. Here's the [MDN doc for Keyboard Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) and [full list of values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values)

Comment: @stealththeninja Thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow keys can captured by `keydown`.

```
var activeQuestion = 1;
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function(ev) {
    if( ev.key === "ArrowLeft" && activeQuestion > 1 ){
      hide( 'question' + activeQuestion ); // hide current element
      show( 'question' + --activeQuestion ); // show next element
    }
    else if(  ev.key === "ArrowRight" && activeQuestion < 3  ){
      hide( 'question' + activeQuestion );
      show( 'question' + ++activeQuestion );
    }
} )

function hide ( elementId ){
  let el = document.getElementById(elementId);
  el.className = el.className.replace( 'active', 'hide' );
}
function show( elementId ){
  let el = document.getElementById(elementId);
  el.className = el.className.replace( 'hide', 'active' );
}
```

Here on example:
https://jsfiddle.net/634vma8r/
click on area of rectangle to work and press -> and <-.